# list combinations in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a table which lists combinations of profiles

```
id | p1 | p2
 1 |  1 | 2
 2 |  2 | 3
 3 |  1 | 3
```

and a table which lists users, and adds a profile to it.

As you can see, a user can have multiple profiles

```
id | user | comb
 1 | John | 1 
 2 | John | 3 
 3 | John | 2 
 4 | Jef  | 1 
 5 | Jef  | 2
```

Now, I'd like to see **per user**, the combinations that are equal to the first table.
excepted output:

```
 | user | comb
 | John | 1,2 
 | John | 1,3 
 | Jef| 2,3
```

How can I best do this in SQL Server 2000 (so no CTE :( )?

I can't get further than this:

```
select * from users where comb in (
select p2 from combinations c inner join users u on u.comb = c.p1
)
```

Comment: can you give us a little more information. What are the combinations? What exactly does the row with id=2 represent?

Comment: the combinations are the different profile ID's the user has. A user can have multiple profiles. The first table lists combinations of profiles. IF the user has these profiles, I should throw a warning that this combination is 'illegal', so that's why I want to search per user, if he has a combination that is 'illegal' (= in the first table)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you are looking for users that have an illegal combination of profiles. You can do that by starting from the illegal_combinations table:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.illegal_combinations ic
JOIN dbo.user_profile p1
ON ic.p1 = p1.comb
JOIN dbo.user_profile p2
ON ic.p2 = p2.comb
AND p1.user = p2.user;
```

That gives you for each combination all users, so you might end up with a user more than once. But that can be fixed easily:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.*
FROM dbo.illegal_combinations ic
JOIN dbo.user_profile p1
ON ic.p1 = p1.comb
JOIN dbo.user_profile p2
ON ic.p2 = p2.comb
AND p1.user = p2.user;
```

Instead of `p1.*` you should use a specific column list. You can include columns from one of the other tables, but then you might get duplicate users again.